# Android ViewPager swipe like notebook page change

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I want to add notebook type ViewPager to swipe like notebook page. I know about simple `ViewPager`. So how can i=I do that? Can I use animation for that or any library available?

Comment: check this sample https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html and http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: thanks alot. any more??

Comment: @Syed Raza Mehdi i know about ViwPager. but i want to animate like page change of notebook...

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement Flip Effect as in a Notebook..

The following three open source libraries will help :

1. **`JazzyViewPager`** : https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager
2. **`CardFlipAnimation`** : https://github.com/balesz/android-tutorial-CardFlipAnimation
3. **`Android Page Curl`**: https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl

The above three libraries can be used to produce an animation like changing the page of a book.

Hope this helps!