# Implement Animation In RecyclerView

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I want to implement [this](http://kjsdeveloper.com/Downloads/2018_03_20_15_43_53.mp4) animation in a project using `RecyclerView`. 
How do I come about it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635109/android-viewpager-swipe-like-notebook-page-change

Comment: check this http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/11/page-flip-animation-in-android.html

Comment: Thanx for your support. I solved my issue using ViewPager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use `ViewPager` not a `RecyclerView`,`ViewPager` will provide many animation transformer

Here is library that help you to add animation https://github.com/geftimov/android-viewpager-transformers

See this it's similar to your requirement https://github.com/geftimov/android-viewpager-transformers/wiki/FlipVerticalTransformer

Comment: Thank you. I will try ViewPager.